# Looking for URL Blacklists of Malicious Websites

Tags: malware, phishing, spyware

Is there a maintained list of URLs that contain malicious content. These URLs may be involved in Phishing, Scams, Viri, or other Malware.

Please indicate in your answer if the list is freely distributed or if there is a cost associated with it.

One list that I have found so far is [PhishTank.com](http://www.phishtank.com)

[URLBlackList.com](http://www.urlblacklist.com) also looked promising.

Comment: I'm just curious, but what for? Sites don't usually like giving away full databases as they spend time/money/effort compiling them and it costs bandwidth/hosting to dump them. Cheers,

Comment: This is a research project to determine classification models that may be used in detecting malicious URLs. I'm taking parts of the URL, and other features of the host, such as DNS, geographic region, to try to build a classifier to detect a url is malicious before the user tries to access it.

Comment: Very cool. Best of luck. I wish i had some additional resources for you but unfortunately I do not. Cheers

Comment: I suspect looking at web logs and email spam might be your best bet for collecting a list yourself. You will still have to classify the URLs manually, which will be hard work, but once you have URLs you can use the lookup services you mentioned to determine whether a URL is malicious or not.  It won't hurt to contact web filtering companies, explain your situation and ask if they can help at all.  The APT1 report has a big list of malicious domains and IP addresses.

Comment: There are some more lists: stackoverflow.com/a/31933878/1601703

Answer (score 8):

[online list of infected or malicious urls](http://zeltser.com/combating-malicious-software/lookup-malicious-websites.html)

[malware domain blocklist](http://www.malwaredomains.com/?page_id=66)

**The malware domain blocklist have over 12000+ domains lists.**

http://malc0de.com/bl/

**1300+  Last updated 2013-03-05**

[Blacklist zeustracker](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=domainblocklist)

800+ listing

[If you are looking for entire compressed DB](http://blocklistpro.com/downloads/biss-ip-blocklists.html)

**UPDATE**

If you are smart enough to write an http parser you can extract the required fields
[Complete URL list](http://www.blade-defender.org/eval-lab/)

Comment: Is there a blacklist available for download? I'm not looking for browser plugins or similar software that tell you whether the site you're currently viewing is malicious or not.

Comment: @msmith0957 unless its an open-source project have you ever thought why these companies would sell their crown jewels to free market?. You should know this information is extracted from expensive and sometimes complex filtering technologies.

Comment: Thanks for the update, some of these may work out. Sadly, they're just the domain, where as I'd prefer a full URL so I can work with lexical features of the URL post TLD. We'll see how it goes :)

Comment: There are some more lists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31933878/1601703